# checkbox jQuery .on() not working in SonataAdminBundle 2.3 with Symfony 2.3

Tags: jquery, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I extended the standard layout template of SonataAdminBundle and added my customized jQuery file, which was as below:

```
$(function () {

    $('input:checkbox[id$="isCoverImage"]').on('click', function() {

        alert('checkbox clicked!');

    }); // end of on

});
```

I'm sure I can select the checkboxes I want by `$('input:checkbox[id$="isCoverImage"]')` (I've tested it by change the format of the checkboxes), but the `.on()` function just can not work. I've also tried `.click()`, `.change()`, but still have no luck, can anyone help?

Comment: Is this element added dynamically? If so, you need to use delegation syntax.

Comment: As suggested by barmar, delegated event is probably the key. Regarding performance, you should delegate to the closest static parent of your target element.

Comment: Thank you two for your prompt reply, yes, the elements were added dynamically, so I changed my code as you suggested but still had no luck, so I did a test, I coded in `$('form').on('click', function() { alert('Test!'); })`, and strangely, if I clicked on some of the textboxed inside the form, the messagebox appeared, but if I clicked on the checkboxes inside the form, nothing happened, it seemed like the checkboxes just didn't propagate the click event, what's the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is Sonata began to use iCheck (to checkbox) [Documentation](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/)

You have to use it, like follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $field  = $('#{{ admin.uniqid ~ "_yourField" }}');


    $field.on('ifChecked ifUnchecked', function(e, aux){
        if( $field.prop('checked') ){
            //put your code
        }else{
           //put your code
        }
    });        

  });
</script>
```